# How can I make my OnClick ReactJS function remember the value I am passing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So, I am trying to make a memory game and I want my function "CompareValue" to remember the last variable I passed
I declared in the script at the beginning MemOne and MemTwo so they are global variables.
Here is my HTML code :

```
function Start(){
var Cartes = [];
const listes_value = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
const randomvalue = [...listes_value, ...listes_value].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

Cartes.push(
    <center key={`row`}> 
        <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", margin: "20px 0" }}>
            <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
                <img src={img} onClick={() => CompareValue(randomvalue[1])} />
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
                <img src={img}  onClick={() => CompareValue(randomvalue[2])} />
            </div>
            <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
                <img src={img}  onClick={() => CompareValue(randomvalue[3])} />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src={img}  onClick={() => CompareValeur(randomvalue[4])} />
            </div>
        </div></center>
```

Here is my CompareValue function

```
function CompareValeur(value){
console.log("value :",value)
console.log("MemOne :",MemOne)
console.log("MemTwo :",MemTwo) 
if (pair % 2 === 0) { 
    var MemOne = value
    console.log("MemOne defined")

    pair++; 
} else { 
    var MemTwo = value
    console.log("MemTwo defined")
    pair++;

}
if (MemOne== MemTwo) { 
    console.log("Success !");
}
return MemTwo, MemOne}
```

Basically what I want my code to do is remember MemOne, and then compare it to MemTwo when another picture is clicked. But it seems that my function forget my variables at the very moment I return them

```
    var MemOne = 0; //Global variable
    var MemTwo = 1; //Global variable
    var pair = 0; //Global variable
```

Here is how I define them at the beginning of my script. Pair is however not lost but I dont' understand why

Comment: There is other HTML tag but they are all the same, so for simplicity I've put only 4 of them, there is 16 in my program, i know i could define them with iteration but I prefer to have it all writed down

Comment: Isn't this a react app? In React you don't work with global variables. But you can use `useState()` to remember the chosen cards: `const [cardOne, setCardOne] = useState();`

Comment: It is a ReactApp, thanks for the tips I'll look at what this is

Comment: Here is a good example: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#adding-state-to-a-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redeclaring a variable inside an if scope.

var MemOne = value => MemOne = value

Reassign, not redeclare

Comment: Thanks ! It was so easy I don't understand how I did not saw it

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest features of `ReactJS` is that it uses the idea of [`state`](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory) to store component-relevant information.

Thus, when you need global variables, especially when it might change the rendering of the component, you can use the [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#) hook:

```js
function Start() {
    var Cartes = [];
    const valueArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    const randomValueArr = [...valueArr, ...valueArr].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    
    // declare it with initial value in your case, 
    // then you can use it within the component like global variable.
    // But also allows the component to re-render when it changes,
    // if you assigned it to the component.
    const [memOne, setMemOne] = useState(0);
    const [memTwo, setMemTwo] = useState(1);
    const [pair, setPair] = useState(0);

    const compareValue = (value) => {
    console.log("value :", value)
    console.log("MemOne :", memOne)
    console.log("MemTwo :", memTwo)
    if (pair % 2 === 0) {
      setMemOne(value);
      console.log("MemOne defined");
      setPair(pair++);
    } else {
      setMemTwo(value);
      console.log("MemTwo defined");
      setPair(pair++);
    }
    if (memOne == memTwo) {
      console.log("Success !");
    }
    return memTwo, memOne; // if the return is not used, it might not be needed.
  }

  Cartes.push(
    <center key={`row`}>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", margin: "20px 0" }}>
        <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
          <img src={img} onClick={() => compareValue(randomValueArr[1])} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
          <img src={img} onClick={() => compareValue(randomValueArr[2])} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
          <img src={img} onClick={() => compareValue(randomValueArr[3])} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src={img} onClick={() => compareValue(randomValueArr[4])} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </center>
```

However, I would also suggest you compose duplicated components out of the main component:

```js
const ClickableImage = (props) => {

    // ...put the compareValue function here

    // import the index for randomValueArr using props.
    // set it like <ClickableImage value={[index_that_you_want]} /> in the main Start() function.
    return (
        <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
            <img src={img}  onClick={() => compareValue(randomValueArr[props.value])} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hope the answer helps.

Comment: I think this answers the OP's question, so I find it weird that the question was closed. It can still be helpful for people who are unfamiliar with creating react components.

Comment: So true and it is sad to find the question was closed - I remembered I once needed something like this to help me get along. Thank you @Kokodoko for your support though!